# How does Indexing a field affect the sorting order of docs without the indexed field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection **students** with few docs

```
[{id:1, name:'AA'}, {id:2, name:'BB'}]
```

I am fetching docs sorted by a field which is not present in the docs

```
db.students.find().sort({marks: -1})
```

It gives me docs in this order

```
[{id:1, name:'AA'}, {id:2, name:'BB'}]
```

Now when I add an index

```
db.students.createIndex({'marks':1})
```

Then call the same query

```
db.students.find().sort({marks: -1})
```

The order was changed!!

```
[{id:2, name:'BB'},{id:1, name:'AA'}]
```

How does indexing a field affect the sorting order of documents which lack that field?

**Note**: This may not be a working example. But my issue is something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongodb will perform sorting in two different times.

1. query time ( without index on that field)
2. indexing time. ( when we create index)
   for that reason you got different result for same query.

**Without index:**

when we perform sort ( without index on sort filed) in mongodb will start sorting collection in querying time by scanning entire collection.

The direction of the sort will be forward( even marks : -1) i.e it will first touches documents on their insertion order( _id value).

When it encounters two documents with same field( marks: null for two documents), then it will arrange them with their _id value.

**With index:**

you created index on marks field in ascending order( Indexing is nothing but generating B-tree with key as marks).

when we try to sort the collection with marks:1 then we will get same results in indexed order.

when we try to sort the collection with marks:-1 then mongodb will start returning documents from backwards because documents already indexed (sorted) in ascending order.

That's why we got different results.

You can get more details on these queries when you perform `explain()` on them.

**Without Index:**

```
db.students2.find().sort({marks:-1}).explain()
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "stackoverflow.students2",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [ ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "SORT",
        "sortPattern" : {
            "marks" : -1
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [ ]
                },
                "direction" : "forward"
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "sys2030",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.2.22",
    "gitVersion" : "105adca0d443f9a1a5abd608fd7133840a68dd"
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

We don't have index so mongodb starts scanning it on query time.

**With Index:**

```
db.students.find().sort({marks:-1}).explain()
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "stackoverflow.students",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [ ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "marks" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "marks_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 1,
            "direction" : "backward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "marks" : [
                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "sys2030",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.2.22",
    "gitVersion" : "105adca0d443f9a1a5abd608fd7133840a68dd"
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

We have index , so mongodb starts using it and simply returns the results from  backwards(marks:-1).

This is the reason when we perform sort when collection is large, monogodb will give error as: sort with large amount of data , without index.

**Further Reading**:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

https://docs.mlab.com/indexing/